# Not able to create new file using FileOutputStream in Servlet

Tags: xml, servlets, file-io, stax

I am using below code for creating a XML file using Stax Parser in one of my project. I used this code before in normal java application and its running fine there. But when I implement this for the Servlet i don't know why its not running. I am not getting any error in this but the **XML** file is not generated.

```
private static ServletContext sc;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sc = config.getServletContext();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/xml");
    System.out.println("Path ==>" + path);

    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    File f = new File(path+"/atms.xml");
    XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f));

    //Some more code
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeStartElement("xxx");

        writer.writeStartElement("yyy");
        writer.writeStartElement("id");
        writer.writeCharacters("1");
        writer.writeStartElement("name");
        writer.writeCharacters("Table");
        writer.writeStartElement("price");
        writer.writeCharacters("110");

        writer.writeEndElement();       
        writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Debug the servlet. I see no error in code except chances Runtime error of `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following:

```
writer.writeEndElement();

writer.writeEndDocument();

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```